# Deploy AWS Lambda function code which is part of Django web app

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs

I have a Django app which serves multiple api calls. It is deployed on Amazon ECS. I now have a requirement to create a Lambda function which can be used as cron job via Cloudwatch event. This Lambda function code will be part of the existing Django app as it has a dependency on the codebase. What's the best way to deploy Lambda code along with the Django app running on ECS?

Comment: is it being a lambda function a requirement here? or could you use a django basecommand + cloudwatch rule to trigger a task definition that runs that command?

Comment: I want to run a scheduled task. If it is possible to use Cloudwatch trigger (scheduled task) to call an api in Django web app running on ECS, it will satisfy my needs.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/
you can write a custom command in Django that will perform any action that you might need, then create a task definition on ECS using the same Django docker image you're using to run the server, but on the `COMMAND` part of the definition, you can add `manage,name_of_the_command`, for example.
then you can set a cloudwatch trigger to run an ECS task (the newly created task definition).
edit: you'll also need a properly configured docker-entrypoint.sh (or equivalent) to run the command.

Comment: I already have one task definition in my ECS cluster. As per your answer, I have to create a new task definition which will work as a scheduled task?

Comment: I imagine that task definition is your Django app running, right? If that is the case, you'll, indeed, need to create a new task definition specifying the command you want to run (that would be the `manage,name_of_the_command` on the `COMMAND` field of your container definition), then you can schedule it using Cloudwatch.

Comment: Create new task definition means i need to create a new docker container with diff command?

Comment: Yes, then you'll set the Cloudwatch rule to schedule that new task definition to run on the same cluster your Django app is running.

Comment: Ok let me try that.

Comment: so it is going to be another container running the same django app where the command will be invoked?

Comment: Yep, that is exactly it!